# C++ - reproduce trim function

Tags: c++

Just asking why I'm not able to delete an interator as the beginning of the string to the end

I tried to do this:

The first called to the erase method work finely but not the second, why ?

```
int main()
{
    std :: string   str{"     Supprimer les espaces a la fin et au debut      "};
    
    std :: string :: const_iterator itStart{ std :: find_if_not(std :: cbegin(str), std :: cend(str), isspace) };
    std :: string :: const_reverse_iterator itEnd{ std :: find_if_not(std :: crbegin(str), std :: crend(str), isspace) };

    std :: cout << *itStart << std :: endl;
    std :: cout << *itEnd << std :: endl;
    str.erase(std :: cbegin(str), itStart);
    str.erase(itEnd, std :: end(str));
    std :: cout << str << "|" << std :: endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After the first call to the erase, the `itEnd` isn't pointing to the same character anymore ... Change the order, or move the definition of `itEnd` after the first call to erase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`erase()` invalidates all iterators for any part of the sequence on or after the point of erasure.

`itEnd` was initialized before the first call to `erase()` and it references the part of the string after the `erase()`d range. As such the first `erase()` call invalidates it. It is no longer valid. Subsequent use of the iterator, in this manner, results in undefined behavior.